# Как получить все цены из торгового каталога Битрикс и вывести их на сайт?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть элемент инфоблока - товар.
У него 2 типа цены - базовая, и дистрибьютерская. Настроено через админку Битрикс.

базовая цена всегда попадает в массив `$arResult`, а вот дистрибьютерская нет.
Как получить дистрибьютерскую цену, и вообще все цены товара из торгового каталога (если бы были еще например оптовая итд) через api битрикса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `CPrice::GetList` [мануал](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/cprice/cprice__getlist.8f7c2a3e.php)

Пример использования:

```
$price_result = CPrice::GetList(
        array(),
        array(
                "PRODUCT_ID" => $PRODUCT_ID,
            )
    );
while ($arPrices = $price_result->Fetch())
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arPrices);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```