# Как вывести цену по ID товара

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин

> Тут принимаю указываю все значения которые нужны мне!

```
$arSelect2 = Array("IBLOCK_ID", "ID", "NAME", "PREVIEW_PICTURE", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL","PROPERTY_RELATED_PRODUCT_VIEW","PRICES");
```

> Тут указываю какой `ID` у `IBLOCK_ID` и принимаю массив с `ID` товаров
>   через `$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["RELATED_PRODUCT_VIEW"]["VALUE"]`

```
$arFilter2 = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>16, "ID"=>$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["RELATED_PRODUCT_VIEW"]["VALUE"], "ACTIVE"=>"Y");

$res2 = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter2, false, Array("nTopCount"=>$result2), $arSelect2);
```

> Дальше вывожу данные которые мне нужно через `while`

```
while($ob2 = $res2->GetNextElement()){
$arFields2 = $ob2->GetFields();
}
```

Вот пытаюсь вывести ссылку на детальную страницу товара

```
<?=$arFields2["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"];?>
```

Вот имя вывожу!

```
<?=$arFields2["NAME"];?>
```

> Выводятся все параметры кроме цены! `<?=$arFields2["NAME"];?>` не
>   получается так вывести

Нужно вывести цену.

> `<?print_r($$arResult["PRICES"]);?>` - вот так я смотрю цены моего
>   товара в карточке товара! И это массив я так понимаю, там есть как и
>   ID так и тип цены а точнее тип валюты!

Как вот теперь вывести цену ?

Comment: я недавно тоже мучался, вот метод из Api битрикса получающий все цены товара из каталога https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991688/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%91%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Воспользовался методом CPrice::GetLis [мануал](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/cprice/cprice__getlist.8f7c2a3e.php).

```
<?
$price_result = CPrice::GetList(
array(),
array(
"PRODUCT_ID" => $arFields2["ID"], // $arFields2["ID"] - этой мой id товара, может быть и число например 12458
"CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => 4 // это группа цены, у меня есть как оптовые так и розничная цена
)
);
while ($arPrices = $price_result->Fetch())
{
$myPricesa = $arPrices["PRICE"]; // тут присваиваю значения переменной 
$myPricesa = substr($myPricesa,0,-3);// цена отображается по умолчанию например 2000.00, эта строчка удаляет с конца три символа! 
$myPricesa = number_format($myPricesa,0,'.', ' ' );// цена отображается как 2000, этот код сам выставляет пробелы! итого получается на выходе 2 000, если будет у нас число 30000 то получится 30 000 и если будет число 300000 то на выходе будет 300 000
}
print_r($$arPrices); // так можно посмотреть все цены этого товара и не только, и тип цены и группу цены и многое другое!
?>
```